# What is the Mandalorian social hierarchy?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett

I really like the Mandalorians as you can see by my name but I don't know all that much about how their society actually works. I know the basics such as that they are hardcore Badass warriors that value strength but I don't know many specifics. I would especially like to know their

1. Social Hierarchy

And

2. How they choose their leaders

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Comment: I feel obligated to note due to the "Boba Fett" tag that our beloved bounty hunter is not, in fact, Mandalorian according the Disney Canon.

Comment: Mandalore>Everyone else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditional command structure and social hierarchy (from [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian#Culture)):

> Mandalorian clan structure was like a pyramid, with the ruler or [Mand'alor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mand%27alor) at the top and the [Protectors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Protectors_(Mandalorians)) enforcing their rule. Below them were the political factions known as [Houses](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian_house), made up of family [Clans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian_clan). For example, [House Vizsla](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/House_Vizsla) was comprised of [Clan Vizsla](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Vizsla) and its allies like [Clan Wren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wren).

However, by the Clone Wars, Mandalore had become mostly pacifist, and was led by Duchess [Satine Kryze](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Satine_Kryze) and the [New Mandalorians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/New_Mandalorians), who appear to have a fairly light hiarchy, with the Duchess being the only noble mentioned.

In the final year of the The Clone Wars, [The Shadow Collective](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Collective) (made up of forces from Death Watch, Black Sun, the Pyke Syndicate, the Hutt Clan, and the Nightbrothers and led by Maul) successfully enacted a coup and took over Mandalore. [Maul](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Maul) ruled the planet at that point.

Maul was later captured by [Darth Sidious](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Sidious), causing his hold on Mandalore to collapse, and allowing [the Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Empire) to take over.

Answer (score -1):

As Rogue Jedi mentioned, there have been changes to Mandalorian social structure over time, however the same principles apply.

Top: Mandalore and the Protectors
Next: Houses and Clans (i.e. Clan Skirata, Clan Fett)
Bottom: Individual members

Comment: This doesn't really add anything that isn't already in my answer.